# Problema al recibir datos en una promesa

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Hago esta pregunta porque tengo un problema a la hora de recibir unos datos en una promesa.

```
return res.status(200).send({message: 'Se ha subido el archivo de video satisfactoriamente.', video: updatedVideo, file_name: file_name});
```

Eso es lo que retorna el controlador de los videos, realizado en NodeJs.

```
        (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.video.setFile(result.file_name);
            alert('Se ha actualizado el video del registro.');
        },
```

y esta es la parte de TypeScript en la que recibo el nombre del archivo. Pero cuando voy a ejecutar la aplicación me indica este error:

> error TS2339: Property 'file_name' does not exist on type '{}'.

El caso es que yo una vez lo he llegado a ejecutar comentando las frases causantes del error, y haciendo que salga en la consola "result" recibo perfectamente file_name, etc. 
¿Alguien que pueda echarme una mano a recibir ese: "file_name" de manera correcta?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes enseñarnos el contenido de: `console.log(result);` tal como sale en la consola?

Comment: {message: "El video se ha actualizado.", video: {…}, file_name: "FBKCfvKQBG84zGKJH36AxIay.jpg"}  Esto es el resumen: Devuelvo el mensaje, el objeto de video y finalmente el nombre del archivo.

Comment: como verás [aquí](http://jsbin.com/buqiyow/edit?html,js,console) funcionaria ... por eso te he preguntado si puedes poner el resultado completo **tal como sale en la consola**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido acceder al valor que necesitaba de esta forma:

```
(result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.video.image = result['file_name'];
        alert('Se ha actualizado la imagen del registro.');
},
```

Muchas gracias aldanux por la atención prestada.

Comment: `result.file_name` es lo mismo que `result['file_name']`. De hecho, si haces: `({ file_name }) => { this.video.image = file_name; }` debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Pues ahí es donde estaba mi problema realmente. Al poner `result.file_name` me daba error... lo puse de esa manera y no da error. La verdad es que me deja un poco loco.